# How to add values from duplicate keys in Perl hash

Tags: perl, unix

Every week I want to parse through the daily logs (on a Red Hat system) and get some statistics on the IP address column. The daily logs contain data with

```
<device>,<ip>,<city>,<packets>
```

like this:

### Sample data - First 5 lines of one of the logs:

```
gw1,25.0.10.61,houston,50
gw1,25.0.20.61,dallas,30
gw1,25.0.30.60,ftworth,80
gw1,25.0.10.61,houston,40
gw1,25.0.10.62,houston,40
```

I'd like to go through all seven logs and determine the total number of packets for each IP address.

The desired output would be

```
<ip>,<packet_count>
```

sorted by packet count from all the seven logs like so:

```
25.0.10.61,480
25.0.10.62,400
25.0.30.60,220
```

etc.

I'm not quite sure if a hash is the best way to do this, and if it is, how to approach it.

Comment: This is an extremely straightforward problem. Please show what code you have written. If you simply need to lean the Perl language then this isn't the place to ask

Comment: The code would have been provided if anyone asked, but it has been solved at this point.  My question at the bottom of my initial post was if the hash was the best way to approach the problem. I had everything coded up to the point of what object to invoke in my loop and I couldn't determine if I should use an array or a hash. I figured it was a hash, but couldn't see how I would add values for duplicate keys... The piece that really put it together for me was bgoldst code specifically  `my $packetCount = $fields->[3]+0;
        $packetCountByIP->{$ip} += $packetCount;
`

Comment: We really shouldn't have to ask for everything, otherwise Stack Overflow questions become an endless dialogue. Ideally, every question would be accompanied by a [*Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but yours shows nothing more than the input and a requirement. I think that's rude and entitled. You've picked up a solution that the better Perl programmers would be ashamed of

Comment: Not one oif your solutions uses *best practice* Perl, and `my $packetCount = $fields->[3]+0; $packetCountByIP->{$ip} += $packetCount;` is a bad hack that needs a comment and may be written much more concisely. I hoped that you would encourage posts that bring great questions and great answers to the top, but this is neither

Comment: I agree you shouldn't have to ask for everything, but I provided what I had. How would I provide an example if I didn't have one? Read my question, I stated I wasn't sure if a hash was the best way to do this. It is not my fault that the responses had code already in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $packetCountByIP = {};
for (my $i = 1; $i <= 7; ++$i) {
    my $fileName = 'activity'.$i.'.log';
    my $fh;
    if (!open($fh,'<',$fileName)) { die("$fileName: $!"); }
    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        my $fields = [split(',',$line)];
        my $ip = $fields->[1];
        my $packetCount = $fields->[3]+0;
        $packetCountByIP->{$ip} += $packetCount;
    } ## end while (log file lines)
    close($fh);
} ## end for (log files)

my $ips = [sort({$packetCountByIP->{$b}<=>$packetCountByIP->{$a}} keys(%$packetCountByIP))];
foreach my $ip (@$ips) {
    print("$ip,$packetCountByIP->{$ip}\n");
} ## end foreach (ips)
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I'm going over it now. I'm assuming you did the **+0** on packet count so that Perl would interpolate the value as a number instead of a string correct?

Comment: @scryptKiddy This is not necessary. It will automatically be used as a number when it's in a numerical context, (next line of code).

Comment: @Chris Charely Thanks. I figured it wasn't needed. One thing I do like about Perl, it seems to be able to interpolate when necessary, however, its not a bad idea to ensure the data that comes in is a number.

Comment: @scryptKiddy @ChrisCharley Conceptually, the `$packetCount` variable should be numeric, so the `+0` type coercion makes sense. It's also better for human-readability and maintainability to capture these type distinctions whenever possible.

Comment: @bgoldst I tried yours first since it was posted first, still troubleshooting, I don't get anything from the foreach at the bottom, so I'm trying to verify the key / values are populating into the hash.

Comment: @bgoldst I was able to get yours to work when I changed the bottom to this for the sorting: `foreach my $ip (sort { $packetCountByIP{$b} <=> $packetCountByIP{$a} }  keys %packetCountByIP) #descending
{
        print "$ip, $packetCountByIP{$ip}\n";
}
`

Comment: @scryptKiddy: Please don't comment about voting

Comment: @bgoldst: *"It's also better for human-readability and maintainability to capture these type distinctions whenever possible"* I believe that's a misconception, and languages like C++ and Java turn type-conformance into an ugly obstacle. Properly used object-oriented code should never need to overload methods at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can use hash for your data.

**code :**

```
my $filename ="log.txt"; #provide your filename here
open FH, $filename or die "Error\n";
my %myhash;
while(<FH>)
{
    chomp($_);
    my @arr = split(/,/, $_);
    $myhash{$arr[1]} +=$arr[3];

}
#access the hash
foreach my $ip (keys %myhash)
{
     print "$ip\t$myhash{$ip}\n";

}
```

Comment: You are storing first, then adding.  Why don't you just add as you go.  What if you had millions of rows?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. It helped me to improve my coding. Thank you again. I have modified my code as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

as a one-liner:

```
perl -F, -lane '
    $count{$F[1]} += $F[3]
  } {
    while (($ip,$n) = each %count) {print "$ip,$n"}
' file*.log | sort -t, -k2,2nr
```

The sorting can be done in perl but it's longer than this.

The trick with the `} {` is to separate the code that should be done for each line, from the code that should only run at the end of the input. That one-liner translates into:

```
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    chomp $_;
    our @F = split(/,/, $_, 0);
    $count{$F[1]} += $F[3];
}
{
    while (($ip, $c) = each %count) {
        print "$ip,$c";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternate approach. I understand the "translates into" section more than the one liner with the exception of BEGIN / LINE, never knew that Perl had that syntax. I'll give em both a test and see how it goes.

Comment: How do I give you and bgoldst credit since both worked?

Comment: If both answers work than upvote both but accept whichever answer you think is the best (most benefit for you and for subsequent readers)

Answer (score 1):

You don't say how to get the names of the log files. This solution just uses `glob` to find the names of all the files ending with `.log` in the current directory. Assigning this list to `@ARGV` allows us to read right through all of the files without explicitly opening them, just as if their names had been entered on the command line

I keep a hash `%data` whose keys are the IP addresses and the values are the accumulated total of the packet counts. I also maintain a width value `$w` which is the length of the longest IP address encountered so far. This is used in `printf` to make the columns align neatly

The ordering of the output is done with a simple sort inside the final `for` loop

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

@ARGV = glob "*.log";

my %data;
my $w;

# <device>,<ip>,<city>,<packets>

while ( <> ) {
    s/\s+\z//;

    my ($ip, $count) = (split /,/)[1,3];

    $data{$ip} += $count;

    my $len = length $ip;
    $w = $len unless $w and $w >= $len;
}

for my $ip ( sort { $data{$b} <=> $data{$a} } keys %data ) {
    printf "%*s %d\n", $w, $ip, $data{$ip};
}
```

#### output

```
25.0.10.61 90
25.0.30.60 80
25.0.10.62 40
25.0.20.61 30
```